# RTSP Server for testing

Tags: android, media-player

I am using YouTube’s RTSP link to demo some capability to the client. Occasionally the mediaplayer fails to display any video (Blank screen). However I am able to hear the sound. Can someone help me understand what is going wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Are you playing this video on an actual phone or in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about youtubes RTSP, but I have had similar problems with youtube not loading the video (but the sound is ok) when the playback quality is changed. I bet that is where your problem lies. I would make sure that you specify playback quality and everything and request that feed before loading it into your player if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Emulator doesn't work with streaming RTSP video. So I suggest you should test your streaming application (video) on real device.

Hope it is useful for you